# XSLT: Select key() OR another key()

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xmi

I have elements connector which has source and target. But source can be sometimes one element sometimes another (initial node or activity). So I have 2 keys for that. I wan to use either one key or the other.
Sample of my XML input:

```
            <packagedElement>
                <node xmi:type="uml:InitialNode" xmi:id="EAID_a" name="ActivityInitial">
                    <outgoing xmi:idref="EAID_A7A0C176_5CCC_4bf2_AED2_AEB05FB741AF"/>
                </node>
                <group xmi:type="uml:ActivityPartition" xmi:id="EAID_b" name="Partition_1">
                    <node xmi:idref="EAID_c"/>
                </group>
                <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Activity" xmi:id="EAID_c" name="Activity1"/>
                <group xmi:type="uml:ActivityPartition" xmi:id="EAID_d" name="Partition_2">
                    <node xmi:idref="EAID_e"/>
                </group>
                <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Activity" xmi:id="EAID_e" name="Activity2"/>
            </packagedElement>
            ...
            <connector xmi:idref="EAID_A7A0C176_f">
                <source xmi:idref="EAID_a"/>        
                <target xmi:idref="EAID_c"/>
            </connector>
            <connector xmi:idref="EAID_CEB43B7F_g"/>
                <source xmi:idref="EAID_c"/>
                <target xmi:idref="EAID_e"/>
            </connector>
```

This is my XSLT:

```
    <xsl:key name="grp" match="group" use="node/@xmi:idref" />
    <xsl:key name="ini" match="*[@xmi:type='uml:InitialNode']" use="@xmi:id" />

    ...

    <connector xmi:idref="EAID_CONNECTR{substring(@xmi:id, 14, 28)}">
         <source xmi:idref="(EAID_LIFELINE{key('grp', @source)/substring(@xmi:id, 14, 28)})({key('ini', @source)/@xmi:id})"/>
         <target xmi:idref="EAID_LIFELINE{key('grp', @target)/substring(@xmi:id, 14, 28)}"/>
    </connector>
```

For two connectors WRONG xml output looks like that:

```
 <connector xmi:idref="EAID_CONNECTR_f">
        <source xmi:idref="(EAID_LIFELINE)(EAID_a)"/>
        <target xmi:idref="EAID_LIFELINE_c"/>
 </connector>
 <connector xmi:idref="EAID_CONNECTR_g">
        <source xmi:idref="(EAID_LIFELINE_c)()"/>
        <target xmi:idref="EAID_LIFELINE_e"/>
 </connector>
```

But XML output should look like that:

```
 <connector xmi:idref="EAID_CONNECTR_5CCC_4bf2_AED2_AEB05FB741AF">
        <source xmi:idref="EAID_a"/>
        <target xmi:idref="EAID_LIFELINE_c"/>
 </connector>
 <connector xmi:idref="EAID_CONNECTR_ED15_4f03_8D9B_8EF054BD458D">
        <source xmi:idref="EAID_LIFELINE_c"/>
        <target xmi:idref="EAID_LIFELINE_e"/>
 </connector>
```

So, if I am using key "grp" there should be prefix EAID_LIFELINE, but if I am using key "ini" there should have all id without prefix.
How edit XSLT for what i want?

Comment: It would be much easier to understand your question if (a) you showed a sample of your input, and (b) you replaced the unreadable hex idref values with 'X', 'Y' and 'Z' to make the whole thing more readable.

Comment: I added sample of my input a replaced idref by a,b,c,d,... Is it more readable?

Comment: Yes, it's more readable, but I'm afraid I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve. The problem is, you've shown the required output, but I have no idea what the rules are that relate this output to the input. Showing us XSLT code that does something completely different doesn't really help.

Comment: Ok, so simple: if there is id from key ini (it means that source is initial node) use id with all name and if you are using key grp (it means that source is activity node - group has id:ref on that) add prefix LIFELINE and use substring from group id.

Comment: Look at difference between wrong xml output and the second output. In first there are (EAID_LIFELINE) and there should´t to be

Comment: So I want to use: "(EAID_LIFELINE key(grp,...) OR (key(ini,...))" but I don´t know how to write that or between keys

Comment: You're really not explaining yourself very well. Just telling me that your code outputs 17 when it should output 42 doesn't tell me how to correct it, given that I have no idea why 42 is the right answer.

Comment: Because there isn´t parenthesis ()

Answer (score 0):

I could make sense of how your current XSLT corresponds to your XML and your expected output, partially because your XSLT is looking for a `@source` attribute, which doesn't exist in your XML.

But to answer in general terms, if you are indeed using XSLT 2.0, this could be a case for the `if ... else ...` construct, so you could write the expression like so:

```
  <source xmi:idref="{
        if (key('grp', @source)) 
        then concat('EAID_LIFELINE', key('grp', @source)/substring(@xmi:id, 14, 28)) 
        else key('ini', @source)/@xmi:id
    }"/>
```

Do also note, that the use of the "ini" key is confusing...

```
key('ini', @source)/@xmi:id
```

Because the "ini" key has a "use" attribute of `@xmi:id`, then it the key would only return anything if `@source` equals the `@xmi:id` on the `node` element. In other words `key('ini', @source)/@xmi:id` is equal to just `@source`.